# How to apply the whole column df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

Tags: pandas

dataset is below

```
,id,revenue ,profit,country
0,101,779183,281257,JPN
1,101,144829,838451,IND
2,101,766465,757565,US
3,101,-35329.7,261071,SA
4,101,1615461,275760,IND
5,101,246731,949229,JPN
6,101,-951518,301016,JPN
7,101,444669,430583,JPN
```

df.info()

```
id                  int64
revenue             float64
profit              object
country             object
```

I have a dataset which is having integer and object.

I need to apply below function if its integer and if object it should not apply

`df.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

- The value error will throw since it is numeric is apply on string.

DO I need to do `try except` or any other method is there like `np.where`?

after apply `df['revenue'] =df['revenue'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')`
 my dtype is converting from `float` to `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
#df=df.astype(object)

df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(df)
```

Comment: my one integer column is converting to object

Comment: @Nons is you have character and number in same column , the column type will be object

Comment: before apply `df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(df)` it is float64

Comment: but before that in column there char and int, float

Comment: @Nons your char not char, since it contain '1', 'aaa' and you want the number become number but still have the character